# Time Discretization

Tags: python, time, physics

I am currently performing research on theoretical physics and would like help with some code.
I have a basic python code that sets up a complex potential flow, of 2 point dipoles.
How for example, could I make these vortices move in time, and measure variables at these timesteps?
I have analytical expressions for everything as a function of time, but how would I set up a code that introduces time? Do I need to use a series of loops? I haven't explored python much

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Look into timer functions to trigger measurements at specific intervals: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/timer-objects-python/

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would help a lot if you add a [mcve].